# VHost in ExpressJS accessing pages of main website

Tags: node.js, express, backend, virtualhost, vhosts

I am using Virtual Host (vhost) in express to link the subdomain to my webpage. But the problem is that the subdomain is also able to load the pages of the main webpage.

Eg. I have website [www.ritish.me](http://www.ritish.me), I tried linking a subdomain [www.blogs.ritish.me](http://www.blogs.ritish.me). I have page [www.ritish.me/projects](http://www.ritish.me/projects), but the page /projects is also working with [www.blogs.ritish.me](http://www.blogs.ritish.me). Like [www.blogs.ritish.me/projects](http://www.blogs.ritish.me/projects).

I have project link in header like:

`<li><a class="nav-link" href="/projects">PROJECTS</a></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I worked on the same and found solution to this problem.

What we can do is, we can redirect our subdomain page to our main domain page. As the subdomain is working on the same server and vhost works as a middleware, the pages will be accessible to all the domains.

```
const express = require('express');
const sub = express();

sub.get('/', function(req, res){
return res.render('subdomain_test');
})
```

This will make the subdomain page separate and will work accordingly. Suppose you have a contact page in the main domain, you can make changes like.

```
sub.get('/contact', function(req, res){
 return res.redirect('http://localhost:8001/contact');
})
```

What this will do is, this will redirect the subdomain to the main domain's contact page. So anyhow if the client side tries to fiddle, they won't have any option instead going to main domain's contact page.